# Function scope: using results from high-level function in low-level function

Tags: r, function, scope

I would like to use the calculations from high-level (outer) function `high_lvl_fun` in in a low-level (inner) function `low_lvl_fun`. The low-level function is an argument of the high-level one (I would like to use different functions with different sets of arguments). My reproducible example:

```
set.seed(101)

low_lvl_fun <- function(x, y){ # low-level (inner) function
  sum((x-y)^2) # Mean Squared Error
}

high_lvl_fun <- function(x, y = NULL, FUN, args){ # high level (outer) function

# Just some toy changes in y to check if the code works
  if(length(y) == 0){
    y <- rep(1, length(x))
  }else{
    y <- rep(2, length(x))
  }

  do.call(FUN, args = args) # Call of low_lvl_fun
}
```

The low-level function computes Mean Squared Error. The high-level function performs some operations on vector `y` and calls the low-level function. Declaration of such an argument and the high-level function call:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
high_lvl_fun(x, y = NULL, FUN = "low_lvl_fun", args = list(x, y))
```

results in such an error:

> Error in do.call(FUN, args = args) : object 'y' not found

I understand that the low-level function assumes that the value of `y` is `NULL` (as declared in high-level function call), however, I don't know how to change the scope in which the low-level function searches for `y`.

The only solution I came up with would be to declare `y` in the global environment:

```
high_lvl_fun2 <- function(x, y = NULL, FUN, args){ # high level (outer) function

  if(length(y) == 0){
    y <<- rep(1, length(x))
  }else{
    y <<- rep(2, length(x))
  }

  do.call(FUN, args = args) # Call of low_lvl_fun
}
```

however, I would like to avoid modifying `y` in the global environment.

**EDIT: (more details)**

The low-level function can take arguments other than `x` and `y`. It may also require only `x` and other arguments, and not `y`, for example:

```
low_lvl_fun2 <- function(x){sd(x)/mean(x)}
```

The other important thing is that high and low-level functions can have the arguments with the same names (like above, where both functions have arguments called `x` and `y`) and it would be good not being forced to rewrite low-level function. Unfortunately, the implementation in the comments suggested by @Andrea does not meet this condition, since matching two arguments with the same names throws an error:

```
high_lvl_fun <- function(x, y = NULL, FUN, ...){ # Function suggested by @Andrea

  dots <- lazy_eval(lazy_dots(...))

  # Just some toy changes in y to check if the code works
  if(length(y) == 0){
    y <- rep(1, length(x))
  }else{
    y <- rep(2, length(x))
  }

  args <- c(list(x , y) , dots)

  do.call(FUN, args = args) # Call of low_lvl_fun
}

# Calling the low-level function at the beginning of the post
high_lvl_fun(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, FUN = "low_lvl_fun", x = x, y = y)
```

> Error in high_lvl_fun(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, FUN = "low_lvl_fun", x = x, 
>   :    formal argument "x" matched by multiple actual arguments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `low_lvl_fun()` takes `x` and `y` only. This should do the job

```
high_lvl_fun <- function(x, y = NULL, FUN ){ # high level (outer) function

  # Just some toy changes in y to check if the code works
  if(length(y) == 0){
    y <- rep(1, length(x))
  }else{
    y <- rep(2, length(x))
  }

  args <- list(x = x, y = y)


  do.call(FUN, args = args) # Call of low_lvl_fun
}
```

Comment: Yup, this would work, however, as I stated, I would like to use different functions with different sets of arguments. In particular, I may want to specify more than two arguments for `low_lvl_fun`.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general solution I would suggest
The use of the ... argument

```
require(lazyeval)

high_lvl_fun <- function(x, y = NULL, FUN, ...){ # high level (outer) function

  dots <- lazy_eval(lazy_dots(...))

  # Just some toy changes in y to check if the code works
  y <- y+1

  args <- c(list(x , y) , dots)

  do.call(FUN, args = args) # Call of low_lvl_fun
}

# Ex 1
f <- function(x, y , z) {x+y+z}
high_lvl_fun (x = 1, y = 2,  FUN = f, z = 3) 

# Ex 2
g <- function(x, y , z, mean , sd) {
  n <- x+y+z
  sum(rnorm(n , mean , sd))

}
high_lvl_fun (x = 1, y = 2,  FUN = g, z = 3, mean = 100, sd = 1)
```

Comment: This function seems to work, however, some functions would require only `x`, some `x` and `y` and some `x` or `x` and `y` with some other arguments. Therefore I would like to avoid declaring `list(x, y)` in `args`. Additionally, specifying `y` for the high-level and low-level functions in the function call produces an error. It was not clear originally, so I have updated the question on the basis of your implementations.

Comment: Assuming that low_level_function will only take arguments from the ... argument then  args <-  dots should do the job
May be I am not properly understanding the problem

Comment: The high-level-function may not require declaration of `y` (since it is `NULL` by default) and therefore it may not be required in the low-level function (but still needs to be computed). The suggested implementation doesn't handle this problem.